# PHP bug while validating user name

Tags: php, validation, debugging

I'm building a website using PHP and I need to validate whether the name entered by the user is correct or not. Since JavaScript is client-side, I cannot completely rely on that, so here's my server-side function to validate the name of the user:

```
function validate_name($name) {
    $name = trim($name);  // only for the purpose of debugging <---- edited comment
    echo $name;
    if (strlen($name) <= 1) {
        return "small";
    } else if (has_numbers($name)) { 
        return "numbers";
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

After this, I check the input and display result accordingly:

```
function final_check() {
    if (validate_name($_POST["first_name"]) == "small") {
        echo "<span class='error'>Your first name cannot be empty</span>";
        return false;
    } else if (validate_name($_POST["first_name"]) == "numbers") {
        echo "<span class='error'>Numbers are not allowed in your first name</span>";
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

When I enter nothing in the `first_name` field, I get the empty error message; when I enter numbers, I get the numbers error message. However, when I do enter a valid name, it gives me the name empty error message.

Here's the post data:

```
Array
(
    [email] => ewf@gmail.com
    [first_name] => qwe
    [last_name] => wqe
    [password] => qwe
    [re_password] => qwe
    [gender] => Male
)
```

Output:

```
Your first name cannot be empty
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? I have been stumped for the past hour trying to fix this and I haven't been able to find a solution.

Comment: so what does `echo $name;` return

Comment: @RenePot I put `echo $name` there for the purpose of debugging. After removing that part, the error still persists.

Comment: I understand. Just want to know what is echoed

Comment: The same thing which is echoed by the `$_POST ` variable: `qwe`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Array
(
    [email] => ewf@gmail.com
    [first_name] => qwe
    [last_name] => wqe
    [password] => qwe
    [re_password] => qwe
    [gender] => Male
)
```

// First_name length = 3

```
function validate_name($name) {
    $name = trim($name);
    echo $name;
    if (strlen($name) <= 1) {
        return "small";
    } else if (has_numbers($name)) { 
        return "numbers";
    } else {
        return true;      // satisfy this case return true
    }
}
```

and here it's becoming like

```
function final_check() {
    if (validate_name($_POST["first_name"]) == "small") {   // if(1 == 'small')
        echo "<span class='error'>Your first name cannot be empty</span>";
        return false;
    } else if (validate_name($_POST["first_name"]) == "numbers") {
        echo "<span class='error'>Numbers are not allowed in your first name</span>";
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

if(1 == 'small') its a string comparison with Boolean which always going to return true.

Please check [this page in the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) to understand the problem.

Comment: so, to fix the question, `===` should be used instead of `==`

Comment: STUPID STUPID STUPID STUPID! So stupid of me, damn! I'm used to Python, forgot about the triple equals, thanks a ton, it worked! :)

Answer (score 1):

try with

```
if (validate_name($_POST["first_name"]) == "small" && !validate_name($_POST["first_name"])) {
    echo "<span class='error'>Your first name cannot be empty</span>";
    return false;
} else if (validate_name($_POST["first_name"]) == "numbers" && validate_name($_POST["first_name"])) {
    echo "<span class='error'>Numbers are not allowed in your first name</span>";
    return false;
}
```

`true == 'small'` will also return `true`

or try with `===` will strictly match the values

```
if (validate_name($_POST["first_name"]) === "small") {
    echo "<span class='error'>Your first name cannot be empty</span>";
    return false;
} else if (validate_name($_POST["first_name"]) === "numbers"=) {
    echo "<span class='error'>Numbers are not allowed in your first name</span>";
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is correct,  however, as other questions pointed out, string with boolean comparison will return true.

To fix this, you should use `===` instead of `==` and all should be fine

Answer (score 1):

What I suggest here is to modify your `validate_name` function, so that it will have only one return type, since it can currently return either a `string` or a `boolean`, which is not a good practice.

For instance you can do something like :

```
function validate_name($name) {
    $name = trim($name);
    echo $name;
    if (strlen($name) <= 1) {
        return "small";
    } else if (has_numbers($name)) { 
        return "numbers";
    } else {
        return "ok"; // or return ""; or whatever string you want.
    }
}
```

Moreover to optimize your code and improve readability, you can change your `final_check` function so that there will be only one call to `validate_name` using a intermediate variabe.

```
function final_check() {
    $valid = validate_name($_POST["first_name"]);
    if ($valid == "small") {
        echo "<span class='error'>Your first name cannot be empty</span>";
        return false;
    } else if ($valid == "numbers") {
        echo "<span class='error'>Numbers are not allowed in your first name</span>";
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to change only final_check() function

```
function final_check() {
if(validate_name($_POST["first_name"])){
 return true;
}else{
    if (validate_name($_POST["first_name"]) == "small") {
        echo "<span class='error'>Your first name cannot be empty</span>";
        return false;
    } else if (validate_name($_POST["first_name"]) == "numbers") {
        echo "<span class='error'>Numbers are not allowed in your first name</span>";
        return false;
    }
  }
}
```